# Can you import data like page view counts to google analytics using data imports?

Tags: logging, import, google-analytics, statistics

I came across a horrible problem: the google tracking code of one of our webpages apparently has not been included for 2 days which where really important to have statistics of inside GA.

The question is, can you import data like page counts of former days to google analytics when you have server logs (or a manually created csv maybe)?

I read this [article](http://cutroni.com/blog/2013/10/30/dimension-widening-import-data-directly-into-google-analytics/) but I dont quite understand if it does what I need. I know its not a programmable question but the forums on this are horrible and questions requarding importing apache server logs are from 2009. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I know there are [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771691/is-there-a-posibillity-to-import-own-data-into-google-analytics?rq=1) on this but none discuss the feature of data imports. Maybe it is possible after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alex**, I am afraid you can't do that.

*Dimension widening* works "on-the-fly", meaning if you have for example author ID as one of the URL parameters, you can tell GA to replace that ID with author name from pre-uploaded value list. But you cannot do that historically.

What you can do is to extract the data with API and then do some log-parsing to get the numbers you need. The basic ones like pageviews, visits, visitors etc. shouldn't be much of an issue.

But unfortunately there is no way you can re-upload the data historically and have all campaign-related information available. Looking at the [Data Collection section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/), if you go to [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) which is behind everything Google Analytics collects, it says:

> The Measurement Protocol only allows developers to collect
>   user-interaction (event / hit) data. It does not allow developers to
>   upload aggregated data like tables.

Also, if you review the [possible parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) - there is no date/time available, so I am pretty sure you cannot technically upload historical data.

Comment: i was afraid of that. do you have any proof to that?

Comment: Alex, I am afraid there is no such quote in Google Analytics documentation. But looking at the Data Collection section, if you go to Measurement Protocol which is behind everything Google Analytics collects, it says: "The Measurement Protocol only allows developers to collect user-interaction (event / hit) data. It does not allow developers to upload aggregated data like tables." Also, review the possible parameters - there is no date/time available, so I am pretty sure you cannot technically upload historical data.

Comment: I have added my comments to the original answer, just to make it visible for everyone.

Comment: Actually, Measurement Protocol does provide a [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) that "Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent.", but unfortunately it doesn't support going very far back in time - "Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed."